# Rebuild failed: trailer not found error during PDF merge with iText for Java

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I'm trying to append a PDF document that I did not create myself (and was not created using the iText library) to another PDF document that I am creating myself using the iText library (version 2.1.7 - I know this an old version but it's what I have to work with right now).

```
Document myDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 15, 15, 15, 15);
ByteArrayOutputStream myDocBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(myDoc, myDocBAOS);
// ...
// add stuff to my PDF
// ...
myDoc.close();

ByteArrayOutputStream finalDoc = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfCopyFields pdfMerger = new PdfCopyFields( finalDoc );

pdfMerger.addDocument( new PdfReader(myDocBAOS.toByteArray()) );
pdfMerger.addDocument( new PdfReader(thirdPartyDocBytes) ); // IOException
```

That last statement that attempts to append the third party document (that I did not create myself) fails with:

> java.io.IOException: Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: trailer not found.
>   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)

I can open the document that's causing the problem in several different PDF viewers without any problem, so it's not corrupt. I've also tried printing the last 1024 bytes, and the last 3 lines of the content are:

> startxref
>   116
>   %%EOF

I'm assuming the `trailer not found` error is referring to the EOF marker, but it's right there on the very last line, so what's the problem? I've been using this library in a couple of projects for years and I've been merging documents in this manner successfully (including a mixture of docs created with iText and third party docs that I didn't create).

---

I tried running a simpler test with:

```
byte[] docBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileReader("/tmp/thirdPartyDoc.pdf"));
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(docBytes);
```

...and I got a more informative error message, but I don't understand what it means:

> com.lowagie.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: xref subsection not found at file pointer 127
>   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)

[This is an example](https://www.centralbank.ie/docs/default-source/news-and-media/legal-notices/settlement-agreements/public-statement-relating-to-settlement-agreement-between-the-central-bank-of-ireland-and-aviva-life-and-pensions-ireland-limited.pdf) of the PDF document that iText is unable to read.

---

I've tried reading in the PDF using the 2 lines above, but with iText 5.5.13 this time, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share the documents? Also, please try to reproduce the issue in a recent version of iText. "it's what I have to work with right now" is unfortunately not a valid argument for the sake of debugging your problem, I hope you can understand that.

Comment: I've added an example of the PDF causing the error. Also, my question is specifically regarding iText 2.x.x (or whatever the latest version is before the jump to v5 - I believe that is 2.1.7). If the answer to my question is that this version of iText is unable to process certain PDF formats, then that is helpful to me.

Comment: Could you also please add the document you are merging it with? To be able to fully reproduce your problem?

Comment: @JorisSchellekens there's no need. The merge is not the issue, although I originally thought that it was. It's the fact that iText (2.1.7) cannot read the PDF. Bottom line is that if you can find some way of running those 2 lines of code in my edit using the PDF document from the subsequent link, then I reckon that will solve the whole problem.

Comment: I tried to load your sample PDF, and I succeeded without any further ado. Thus, either the file `/tmp/thirdPartyDoc.pdf` is not identical with the file you provided or `IOUtils.toByteArray(newFileReader("/tmp/thirdPartyDoc.pdf"))` does not contain the content of that file.

Comment: By the way, your method name `newFileReader` contains `Reader` which in Java usually is used for *text* files. Do you, by any chance, use a Java `*Reader*` class in that method?

Comment: OK, the `FileReader` was the problem with iText reading the PDF. Changing it to `FileInputStream` fixed it. I've also ran a test that creates a couple of dummy PDFs with iText and then tried to merge them with the PDF i've been having the problem with. It was successful, so I suspect the method to retrieve the PDF (which I have stored in Amazon S3) is possibly corrupting the PDF somehow. I'll investigate it and if this turns out to be the cause, I'll delete the question.

Comment: I found out that the problem was caused by an older version of iText that my development server was using. My personal machine was using 2.1.7, my dev server was using an older version (I don't know what the version is though, but I know it's older than 2.1.7). When I updated the dev server to 2.1.7, the problem is solved. Maybe I should delete this question? I don't think it will be of any use to anyone...

Comment: An older version of iText... probably one that only fully supported PDFs according to the 1.4 reference. PDF 1.5 introduced an alternative way for encoding the pdf object cross references, and your sample file makes use of them.